# Encrypting/Decrypting sensitive information from Telemetry in Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I am currently facing an issue where some sensitive data (api keys, passwords, PII, etc) are sent from an ASP.NET Core API to Azure Application Insights as Traces via Telemetry and are visible as clear text. Here's an example (the red lines are what I'm talking about):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am fairly new to Azure so I am not sure what is the best way to go about this.

My current course of action is to use an [Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) to "intercept" each telemetry data and obfuscate it before it is sent to Azure.

Since every occurrence of sensitive data I have found in Application Insights follows the format `"property": "value"` or `property: value` or `property=value`, I can use Regular Expressions to capture and obfuscate it. So for instance the following:

```
X-API-Key: abcdef0123456789
{
  "username": "MyUsername",
  "password": "qwerty1234"
}
```

Would become:

```
X-API-Key: [obfuscated]
{
  "username": "[obfuscated]",
  "password": "[obfuscated]"
}
```

And this works for several keywords I have identified following my initial audit (username, password, address, phone, etc.) This is where I'm standing right now.

But then comes another concern: we might want to know what the initial obfuscated values are, for debugging purposes. For example, a call might fail because a client is using an invalid API key so we need to be able to somehow view that API key to determine that this is the cause of the problem.

So I'm thinking I could encrypt the data, rather than obfuscate it as shown above. But what about decrypting the data when we need it? Would we need to have a decryption tool on the side where we would copy paste the value to decrypt? That sounds like a hassle.

So my questions are:

1. Am going the right way about it with the whole Regex thing?
2. Isn't there something in Azure that can handle the encryption/decryption seamlessly? I'm thinking maybe something where we would tell Azure which patterns to encrypt and then the original values would be stored in some kind of secured storage like a vault and associated with the trace ID or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure about option 2 but what is it you're trying to protect against by going that route? Do you have users you want to be able to see the logs but not the encrypted parts and then some users who should be able to see the encrypted values too?

I think a side-tool for decryption could be a reasonable way to go, if you're feeling fancy you could probably even build it as a browser extension to decrypt it right there in the App Insights UI (if you're okay putting the key in your extension's user settings or the like anyway).

Comment: If you are using an HTTPS secure connection then it's not clear text anyway

Comment: @Charlieface it's not about whether the data can be sniffed across the network it's about not storing sensitive values in our logs.

Comment: @Jessica it's an extra layer of security. Our Azure portal is only accessible to the people who need it. I guess the idea is to protect ourselves (and our users) in case of a security breach. Sure if someone unauthorized somehow gains access to our Azure subscription, we'll have issues anyway. But as long as it only impacts our applications that's our problem, but if our users' data are exposed, that's a different story.

Comment: @Sulli I see, OK well then I do think your best bet is to encrypt it with like RSA or the like in your application code and provide a tool for decrypting the values when you need them. Obviously this does mean you can't sort or search based on those values but presumably this is not a problem. If anything I think your biggest challenge is going to be detecting secrets/PII in the first place to know that they need to be encrypted. You'll probably also need some way to indicate where the encrypted values are and also you may need to embed a key ID should you ever need to rotate encryption keys.

Comment: @Jessica Ok so it's as I thought then. I'll keep going the way I started. Thanks for helping settle this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Azure Key Vault to encrypt the sensitive data before sending it to Application Insights.

> Azure Key Vault is a cloud service that provides secure storage of keys, secrets, and certificates. You can use Azure Key Vault to encrypt the sensitive data and then store the encrypted data in Application Insights.

To use Azure Key Vault, you need to create a Key Vault instance and then create a key or a secret in the Key Vault. You can then use the Azure Key Vault SDK to encrypt the sensitive data before sending it to Application Insights.

Azure Key Vault to encrypt the sensitive data.

1. Create a Key Vault instance in Azure.
2. Create a key or a secret in the Key Vault.
3. Use the Azure Key Vault SDK to encrypt the sensitive data before sending it to Application Insights.
4. Store the encrypted data in Application Insights.

You can then use the Azure Key Vault SDK to decrypt the data when you need it.

> using Regex, it is a good approach to obfuscate the sensitive data. But it is not a secure way to protect the data. Anyone with access to the data can easily reverse engineer the obfuscated data.

Using Azure Key Vault to encrypt the sensitive data is a more secure way to protect the data.

> I created a key vault and secret. And used Azure Key Vault SDK to encrypt the sensitive data before sending it to Application Insights.

[image]

App Insights

[image]

[image]

**Csharp Code**

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://keyvault.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret("mysecret");
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration("InstrumentationKey"));

var telemetryItem = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.TraceTelemetry("MySensitiveData");
var encryptedData = secret.Value;
telemetryItem.Properties.Add("Secret", encryptedData);
telemetryClient.TrackTrace(telemetryItem);
telemetryClient.Flush();

var decryptedData = Decrypt(secret.Value, encryptedData);


private static string Encrypt(string key, string data)
{
    var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = keyBytes;
        aes.GenerateIV();
        var iv = aes.IV;
        using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            var encryptedData = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
            var encryptedBytes = new byte[iv.Length + encryptedData.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, encryptedBytes, 0, iv.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedData, 0, encryptedBytes, iv.Length, encryptedData.Length);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
        }
    }
}


private static string Decrypt(string key, string encryptedData)
{
    var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
    var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData);
    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = keyBytes;
        var iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
        aes.IV = iv;
        using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            var encryptedDataBytes = new byte[encryptedBytes.Length - iv.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, iv.Length, encryptedDataBytes, 0, encryptedDataBytes.Length);
            var decryptedDataBytes = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedDataBytes, 0, encryptedDataBytes.Length);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedDataBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

For further information refer to [Azure Key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview) and [Azure Key vault Security Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/security-features)

Comment: Where did this quote come from? Key Vault isn't an encryption service.

Comment: You can use Azure Key Vault to encrypt the sensitive data before sending it to Application Insights.

Azure Key Vault is a cloud service that provides secure storage of keys, secrets, and certificates. You can use Azure Key Vault to encrypt the sensitive data and then store the encrypted data in Application Insights.

To use Azure Key Vault, you need to create a Key Vault instance and then create a key or a secret in the Key Vault. You can then use the Azure Key Vault SDK to encrypt the sensitive data before sending it to Application Insights.

Comment: Yes, Key vault is not an encryption service, where as using this approach, we can Encrypting/Decrypting sensitive information from Telemetry in Application Insights

Comment: You're repeating what you wrote in the question. That doesn't make it right. Nor does it explain where that invalid quote came from. The code doesn't encrypt anything, on the contrary it sends the unencrypted secret to Application Insights

Comment: Where's the encryption code? `telemetryItem.Properties.Add("Secret", encryptedData);` stores the *decrypted secret* as an application-defined property, it doesn't encrypt anything. It exposes more informatino

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252897/discussion-between-rajesh-m-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: @RajeshM I have to agree with the others, I can't really make sense of your example. You're fetching a secret from Azure Key Vault (which I guess would be the encryption key): `KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret("mysecret");` Only to send it to App Insights: `telemetryItem.Properties.Add("Secret", secret.Value);`. When you say I can use KeyVault to encrypt/decrypt, I think what you mean is I can store the encryption key within KeyVault and then retrieve that key and use it within my code to encrypt/decrypt my data. But that's not what your sample code does.